# Why didn't River know what would happen to The Doctor at Lake Silencio?

Tags: doctor-who, time-travel, timeline

I'm talking about the Season 6 finale "*The Wedding of River Song*", about this moment:

[image: Astronaut shoots The Doctor on Lake Silencio]

I'm specifically talking about the moment

> when River is *inside* the astronaut's suit, not about the River that watches the whole scene from where the photo is taken.

<sub>(I won't bother with spoiler boxes from now, because this won't show up in the preview)</sub>

---

Okay, so River and The Doctor always meet in reverse order. The Doctor's future is River's past and The Doctor's past is River's future. She has already fallen in love with him and obviously knows him well. That means, she remembers The Doctor from her past. Again, her past is The Doctor's future.

If The Doctor has a future, and what happens at Lake Silencio is a fixed event in time, The Doctor **cannot** die there. She is really clever and quite used to this sort of 4-dimensional thinking, so it shouldn't be hard for her to put one and one together.

So how about that? How come she doesn't realise, that "shooting" him there <s>will not</s> cannot hurt him?
Note: She just learns at her wedding, just before going back to the Lake, that this is not the real Doctor.

Comment: I would say she was playing along.

Comment: You can see her crying in her helmet and only The Doctor could possibly see her. Also, she hesitated to shoot him, causing the entire time to collapse.

Comment: Even knowing what will happen, shooting someone you don't want to would still be a difficult action for someone who is not a time traveling robot.

Comment: HAHA! +1 on comment for time traveling robots! LOL

Comment: And it's doubly good, since it references all our favorite troll while ALSO being about an **ACTUAL** time traveling robot!  ;)

Comment: @eidylon: Well, the involved "robot" wasn't the one doing the shooting :)

Comment: She doesn't always meet in exactly reverse order. It's more jumbled than that, though it is a generally backwards direction. See http://willbrooks.deviantart.com/art/River-Song-Timeline-Series-4-7a-288713635 for one possible timeline. She probably hadn't met the Doctor further in his timeline by then, or didn't know that it *was* further in his timeline.

Comment: _"Okay, so River and The Doctor always meet in reverse order."_ I stopped reading here, because this is not true.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: How good for you that you have such efficient content filtering algorithms. Why is that relevant to me?

Comment: @bitmask: The fact that the entire premise of your question is incorrect is not "relevant to [you]"?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Your critique is clearly targeting the absolute formulation, implying that they meet exactly in reverse order, which I grant you is imprecise. The premise of my question requires only them to meet in roughly reverse order. Given that your comment is not constructive but only tells me what you do with your time (i.e. not reading a question), rather than just fixing the [wording of] question or posting an answer, I'm curious as to why I'm supposed to care about it.

Comment: @bitmask: Charming

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Yes, people keep asserting that. ;)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think this timeline helps establish what happened:

[image]

River Song shoots the Doctor at the fixed point in time, after being abducted by Madame Kovarian and the Silence and put into the astronaut's suit.  This is post-Melody incarnation, so she has met and knows the Doctor already.

However the two of them do not meet in a perfect forward-backward sequence.  The relevant example is River Song meeting the Doctor for the first time as Mel, as this obviously happens in between the Doctor meeting River Song at other times.

This exception is the timeline you're interested in:

- Melody meets the Doctor, regenerates into River Song, kills the
  Doctor with the kiss, gives her remaining regenerations to save him
  and then enrols in Luna University (Let's Kill Hitler).
- River
  graduates from university and is seized by the Silence. (end of
  Closing Time)
- River appears in the astronaut suit and shoots the
  Doctor. (The Impossible Astronaut/The Wedding of River Song)

**This timeline is independent and precedes the other River/Doctor meetings.**  There may have been meetings in between the first two points above but it is unlikely because as you point out and Steven Moffatt confirms (Doctor Who Confidential: The Wedding of River Song):

> She has her adventures roughly, broadly speaking in reverse order to
>   the Doctor.

As a result, River does not know that the Doctor cannot die there.  After all he would not have revealed that fact to her ("Spoilers!"), so as far as she knows the version of the Doctor she killed (or is about to kill) is the final version of the Doctor.

If that does your head in like it does mine, just think "timey wimey stuff" and admire this alternate interpretation of their timeline:

[image]

Comment: Is there a larger version of the timeline you can link to?

Comment: @Xantec: Just open the picture itself, it is sufficiently large enough to read.

Comment: Caveat: neither are mine, but I do love the second one.  Especially the David Tennant cameo.

Comment: I made the first picture a link to the larger version.  Hopefully that will help.

Comment: In "The Wedding of River Song"  confidential, River herself explains her timeline.

Comment: @Thecafremo Good catch.  I went and rewatched it and they show the relevant scenes in sequence.  Makes it a lot easier to explain and get my head around!